# Migrating / Upgrading NUnit to Team system

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, automated-tests

We are working on a C# windows application that is being upgraded from **.Net** **1.1** to **3.5**.
The application uses **NUnit** for **automated testing** and we are in turn changing this to **Team System 2008**.

- It seems to me that NUnit uses
  similar **attributes** and code for
  **assertion**?
- What is the best way to **upgrade** /
  **migrate** this code and are their any
  **procedures** **to** **avoid**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly, converting between test frameworks is a "[Ctrl]+H" (replace all) job. However...

I think the word "upgrade" may be confusing. I've used both, and in many ways NUnit has a lead on MSTest. The biggest advantage of MSTest is (IMO) with the team-coverage integration in the IDE - but you can get this **with your existing NUnit tests** via [TestDriven.NET](http://testdriven.net/) (Test With -> Team Coverage).

Things to watch out for with MSTest:

- it needs a solution file to hold the testrunconfig etc
- you need to add extra attributes (or entries in the testrunconfig) to deploy files to the test folder (it doesn't just use the output "bin" folder)
- instrumentation needs a special config

Comment: Should i do this manually? What is the easiest way to add things things? 

Perhaps using: "Create unit test" and thus putting in the old code and replacting methods that automatically were created?

Comment: Well, "Create Unit Test" will setup the project etc, certainly - just merge in your tests, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how attributes map from NUnit to MSTest

```
[TestFixture] -> [TestClass]
[Test] -> [TestMethod]
[SetUp] -> [TestInitialize]
[TearDown] -> [TestCleanup]
[TestFixtureSetUp] -> [ClassInitialize]
[TestFixtureTearDown] -> [ClassCleanup]
```

You can consider adding something like

```
using TestClassAttribute = NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute;
using TestAttribute = NUnit.Framework.TestMethodAttribute;
```

to the top of your test classes.

Comment: Here are moreattributes: http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/01/31/migrating-from-nunit-to-mstest.aspx